# Regarding Transport layer protocols implementation in java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

Is there any connectionless reliable protocol implementation in java? Other than sockets, datagrams or Socketchannels(in NIO), I want to know if there exists any library which can provide a protocol implementation like the one described here:- 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol

Or is there any way we can write a wrapper over conventional sockets to make them connectionless but preserving all the TCP properties at the same time except but for the 3-way handshaking.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[Mobile Reliable UDP (MR-UDP)](http://lac-rio.com/mr-udp/)

Here's MR-UDP's Hello World example:

**Server**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import net.rudp.*;

public class HelloServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 10341;

    ReliableServerSocket serverSocket = new ReliableServerSocket(port);
    Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

    System.out.println(buffReader.readLine());

    serverSocket.close();
  }
}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import net.rudp.*;

public class HelloClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 10341;

    ReliableSocket clientSocket = new ReliableSocket(host, port);
    ReliableSocketOutputStream outputStream = (ReliableSocketOutputStream) clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter outputBuffer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

    outputBuffer.println("Hello World MR-UDP!");
    outputBuffer.flush();

    clientSocket.close();
  }
}
```

Also, a quick search on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=rudp&type=Repositories) shows some projects about RUDP, like:

- https://github.com/Serkan/rudp
- https://github.com/GermanCoding/RUDP
- https://github.com/Elitward/SimpleRUDP
- https://github.com/joshuaar/RUDP_Share
- https://github.com/JianweiWang/rudp-1.2.3